# What are the recent advancements in mathematics that an undergraduate can understand?

Tags: reference-request, conjectures

I am an undergraduate student of mathematics. I am interested to know the conjectures that are proved in the last, say 5 or 10 years. Or any other development. Preferably in pure mathematics. One of the motives to ask this question is to get a feel for the cutting edge research areas. (If you feel this is too broad, please suggest me in comments to improve this question.)

**EDIT:** I am interested to understand (not just know the statement of) the theorems. In your answers, you could just state the theorems, with references where I can research. If proofs are also provided, that would of course be acknowledged with deeper gratitude.

Comment: Are you interested in theorems or theorems together with proofs?

Comment: If theoretical computer science is acceptable, have you read "PRIMES is in P"?

Comment: The statement of the Green Tao theorem can be understood easily. Not sure about the proof though.

Comment: It seems a tad optimistic for an undergraduate to be able to understand not only the statements of recent results but also their proofs. And this _especially_ if you are interested in results that used to be conjectures (many results never go through this status), in other words that have for substantial amount of time resisted the most "obvious" approaches that were no doubt tried on them. In math, more even then in most other subjects, getting to the forefront of research requires a lot of studying "known" things first.

Comment: I agree with you that I have a lot of things to learn. However, I did not require that the recent developments had to be conjectures. Sorry if my question implied so.

Comment: Could someone help me move this question to mathoverflow? Perhaps I could get some attention over there!

Comment: Your question didn't merely imply so, it blatantly stated it: "the conjectures that are proved in the last..."

You can manually re-ask the question on Mathoverflow, I doubt anyone will mind.

Comment: I went on to say "Or any other development...". Anyway, I found a similar question [here on mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/129759/modern-mathematical-achievements-accessible-to-undergraduates/135284?noredirect=1#comment374495_135284)